# Adding the following picture

Tags: diagrams, xcoffins

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab,moreverb} % tableau de signe moreverb not needed
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} %pour inserer une page pdf
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % pagestyle
%---- Dimensions des marges ---
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\onehalfspacing
%----New Structure Exercice -----
\newtheoremstyle{sboxexc}% name of the style to be used
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\itshape}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
  {0pt}%  of space to indent
  {\bfseries}% name of head font
  {}% punctuation between head and body
  { }% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
  {\thmname{#1}}% Manually specify head
\newcounter{counter}
\setcounter{counter}{1}
\theoremstyle{sboxexc}
\newcommand{\optionaltext}{}
%\newtheorem*{Exc}{\shadowbox{Exercice \arabic{counter}\optionaltext}}
\newtheorem*{Exc}{\shadowbox{Exercice \arabic{counter}\optionaltext}\\}
\newcommand{\exo}[2][]{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{#2}\begin{Exc}\normalfont}
%\newcommand{\exo}[2][]{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{#2}\begin{Exc}\normalfont $\:$} %Return to line with itemize
\newcommand{\finexo}{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{}\end{Exc}\addtocounter{counter}{1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{sfaxlogo}{RGB}{127,176,206}
\colorlet{sfaxblue}{sfaxlogo!70!black!60!blue}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%begin entete%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Faculté des Sciences Economiques et Gestion de Mahdia
{
{\noindent
      \small{\textbf{Université de xxxxxxxxx} }             % Université
      \hfill A.U. : 2020-2021 \\                 % année
}{\noindent
    \small{ {\large{F}}aculté des {\large{S}}ciences {\large{\'E}}conomiques et de {\large{G}}estion de {\large{M}}xxxxx   }            % institut
      \hfill \textbf{Module : xxxxxxxx} \\    % section et module
}
{\noindent
      \small{\textbf{Département des xxxxxxxxxxx}   }           % Université
      \hfill \ding{43} Section : xxxxx}              % année
%------------------------------------------------------
\vspace{-0.4cm}
\begin{center}
\section*{{\shadowbox{\ding{45} Série N°{\huge1}: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}}}
\end{center}
%--------------------------end entete----------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

I want to insert a picture

[image]

Comment: Is it a header (for every page) or only the heading for the first page of the document?

Comment: @Bernard It is only for the first page Professor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a big top aligned two-row tabular to contain the whole header.

The first row has three nested center aligned tabulars, for the left part, the image and the right part.

The second row has the “Série” box.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement
%---- Dimensions des marges ---
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,showframe}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%begin entete%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Faculté des Sciences Economiques et Gestion de Mahdia

\noindent
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
\makebox[\textwidth][s]{%
  \small
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \textbf{Université de xxxxxxxxx} \\
  {\large F}aculté des {\large S}ciences {\large \'E}conomiques 
  et de {\large G}estion de {\large M}xxxxx \\
  \textbf{Département des xxxxxxxxxxx}
  \end{tabular}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[height=3\normalbaselineskip]{example-image}
  \end{tabular}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
  A.U. : 2020-2021 \\
  \vphantom{\large \'E}\textbf{Module : xxxxxxxx} \\
  \ding{43} Section : xxxxx
  \end{tabular}%
}% end of top row
\\[4ex]
\shadowbox{\Large\ding{45} \bfseries S\'erie N°{\huge1}: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
\end{tabular}
%--------------------------end entete----------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

The `showframe` option is just for showing the page margins, remove it from the production version.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Professor but I cannot compilate your codes

Comment: @Schüler Possibly the `é`?

Comment: He shows me that the problem is here ```}% end of top row```

Comment: @Schüler I have no problem; what's the error message?

Comment: Now when I add ```  \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}``` it works . Thanks

Comment: Please why is the importance for adding ```\vphantom{\large \'E}``` before ```\textbf{Module : xxxxxxxx}``` ? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Schüler It's to balance the large letters on the left side

Comment: Dear Professor @egreg Could you please see this question. I'm sure you will help me to get a nice template for my exams. thanks a lot https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578437/text-between-two-pictures/578444?noredirect=1#comment1456045_578444

Answer (score 3):

I would do it with a `tabular*{\linewidth}}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcr@{}}` environment,and adjusting by hand the position of the logo.

*Unrelated* The  ‘francais’ option for babel-french is obsolete. Use `french` instead. Also, you don't have to load `inputenc` if you have a comparatively recent version of latex: `tf8` is now the default, and you can type directly `É`, instead of `\'E`. Also, don't forget to load  the `T1` font encoding for a correct hyphenation.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab} % tableau de signe moreverb not needed,moreverb
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} %pour inserer une page pdf
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % pagestyle
%---- Dimensions des marges ---
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\onehalfspacing
%----New Structure Exercice -----
\newtheoremstyle{sboxexc}% name of the style to be used
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\itshape}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
  {0pt}% of space to indent
  {\bfseries}% name of head font
  {}% punctuation between head and body
  { }% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
  {\thmname{#1}}% Manually specify head
\newcounter{counter}
\setcounter{counter}{1}
\theoremstyle{sboxexc}
\newcommand{\optionaltext}{}
%\newtheorem*{Exc}{\shadowbox{Exercice \arabic{counter}\optionaltext}}
\newtheorem*{Exc}{\shadowbox{Exercice \arabic{counter}\optionaltext}\\}
\newcommand{\exo}[2][]{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{#2}\begin{Exc}\normalfont}
%\newcommand{\exo}[2][]{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{#2}\begin{Exc}\normalfont $\:$} %Return to line with itemize
\newcommand{\finexo}{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{}\end{Exc}\addtocounter{counter}{1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{sfaxlogo}{RGB}{127,176,206}
\colorlet{sfaxblue}{sfaxlogo!70!black!60!blue}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%begin entete%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Faculté des Sciences Economiques et Gestion de Mahdia
{\centering\small \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth} {@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcr@{}}
\textbf{Université de xxxxxxxxx} & & A.U. : 2020-2021 \\ % année
{\large F}aculté des {\large S}ciences {\large É}conomiques et de {\large G}estion de {\large M}xxxxx & \raisebox{-0.4\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{zwinkern}}& \textbf{Module : xxxxxxxx}\\
\textbf{Département des xxxxxxxxxxx} & & \ding{43} Section : xxxxx
\end{tabular*}}
%--------------------------end entete----------------------------------------------------

\begin{center}
\section*{{\shadowbox{\ding{45} Série N°{\huge1}: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not difficult to do if you use the package `xcoffin`.

https://ctan.org/pkg/xcoffins?lang=en

Try this code. To see how this works see

[Align text both horizontally and vertically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571769/align-text-both-horizontally-and-vertically/571803#571803)

The logo is 3 baselines high to match both texts. It can be scrolled horizontally (or vertically) by adding an offset (now set to 5pt). Note that the correct alignment of the text lines will not change by changing the position or the size of the logo since they all are independent boxes.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab,moreverb} % tableau de signe moreverb not needed
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} %pour inserer une page pdf
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % pagestyle
%---- Dimensions des marges ---
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\onehalfspacing
%----New Structure Exercice -----
\newtheoremstyle{sboxexc}% name of the style to be used
{\topsep}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
{\topsep}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
{\itshape}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
{0pt}%  of space to indent
{\bfseries}% name of head font
{}% punctuation between head and body
{ }% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
{\thmname{#1}}% Manually specify head
\newcounter{counter}
\setcounter{counter}{1}
\theoremstyle{sboxexc}
\newcommand{\optionaltext}{}
%\newtheorem*{Exc}{\shadowbox{Exercice \arabic{counter}\optionaltext}}
\newtheorem*{Exc}{\shadowbox{Exercice \arabic{counter}\optionaltext}\\}
\newcommand{\exo}[2][]{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{#2}\begin{Exc}\normalfont}
%\newcommand{\exo}[2][]{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{#2}\begin{Exc}\normalfont $\:$} %Return to line with itemize
\newcommand{\finexo}{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{}\end{Exc}\addtocounter{counter}{1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{sfaxlogo}{RGB}{127,176,206}
\colorlet{sfaxblue}{sfaxlogo!70!black!60!blue}

\usepackage{xcoffins}  % added

\NewCoffin\Framex   
\NewCoffin\LeftUniv
\NewCoffin\Logox
\NewCoffin\RightMod

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%begin entete%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Faculté des Sciences Economiques et Gestion de Mahdia
%   \SetVerticalCoffin\Framex{\textwidth}{\phantom{x}} % an empty box \textwidth wide
\SetHorizontalCoffin\Framex{} % an empty box \

\SetVerticalCoffin\LeftUniv{0.6\textwidth}{%
    \noindent 
    \small{\textbf{Université de xxxxxxxxx} } \newline   % Université
    \small{ {\large{F}}aculté des {\large{S}}ciences {\large{\'E}}conomiques et de {\large{G}}estion de {\large{M}}xxxxx }   % institut 
    \small{\textbf{Département des xxxxxxxxxxx}   } % Université
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\Logox{0.15\textwidth}{\includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip, keepaspectratio]{example-grid-100x100pt}}

\SetVerticalCoffin\RightMod{0.25\textwidth}{%
    \raggedleft
    A.U. : 2020-2021 
        \textbf{Module : xxxxxxxx}    % section et module 
    \ding{43} Section : xxxxx            % année
}
    
\JoinCoffins*\Framex[l,vc]\LeftUniv[l,vc]
\JoinCoffins*\Framex[\LeftUniv-r,\LeftUniv-vc]\Logox[l,vc](5pt,0pt)  % X Y offsets. Use to displace the logo <--->
\JoinCoffins\Framex[r,vc]\RightMod[r,vc](\textwidth,0pt)

\noindent\TypesetCoffin\Framex

%{\noindent
%      \small{\textbf{Université de xxxxxxxxx} }             % Université
%      \hfill A.U. : 2020-2021 \\                 % année
%}{\noindent
%    \small{ {\large{F}}aculté des {\large{S}}ciences {\large{\'E}}conomiques et de {\large{G}}estion de {\large{M}}xxxxx   }            % institut
%      \hfill \textbf{Module : xxxxxxxx} \\    % section et module
%}
%{\noindent
%      \small{\textbf{Département des xxxxxxxxxxx}   }           % Université
%      \hfill \ding{43} Section : xxxxx}              % année
%------------------------------------------------------
%\vspace{-0.4cm}
\begin{center}
\section*{{\shadowbox{\ding{45} Série N°{\huge1}: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}}}
\end{center}
%--------------------------end entete----------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image: g2]